# java 11 on MacOS not working as it cannot find main class

Tags: java, bash, macos

I went through all of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean), but still run into the

```sh
java -classpath . HelloWorld
> Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

```java
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    
    }
    
}
```

`javac HelloWorld.java` runs without problems (before calling `java HelloWorld`)

Java version:

```sh
java --version
> java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

all commands executed in terminal from the directory, where the code is.

Operating System: *MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258)*

**What can I do to get java up and running from command line?**

Comment: Are you running this in a terminal, from the directory that contains your source file? If not, then you have to [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) to that directory first.

Comment: Please post *real* commands and error messages along with a snippet of code

Comment: Yes, I do @Jesper

Comment: Done @Gyro Gearless! 

Comment: Did you compile your code first? `javac HelloWorld.java` and then run it with `java HelloWorld` or `java -cp . HelloWorld` or `java -classpath . HelloWorld`

Comment: Permissions should be good as well, as I get the same result running with `sudo` in front of `java`

Comment: There are two ways of running a java class: A) you do javac + java B) you go `java SomeClass.java` directly. You are mixing those two ways ... in a way that doesn't work.

Comment: Sudo could have created a class file with permissions that don't allow the un-sudo user to access it.

Comment: Meaning: when you have a SINGLE class that is self contained, and can be compiled on its own, then `java ThatClass.java` compiles and runs from JAVA source. Otherwise, as said, you first need to run javac, then you invoke `java` with the CLASS name.

Comment: Didn't work before and after the sudo command was added. Permissions are `-rw-r--r--`owner: my local username

Comment: @Ghostcat: I did compile with javac HelloWorld.java before running java HelloWorld

Comment: Then you want to ensure that you have that file `HelloWorld.class` sitting in the directory you are invoking `java -classpath . HelloWorld`

Comment: @GhostCat: yes, Hello world.class is in the same folder - after compiling with javac.

Comment: I don't think I am mixing A & B @GhostCat. I'm only doing A. It was the spell checker, that removed the c here from javac. I've edited the question accordingly. 

Comment: Maybe you are mixing letter case? (e.g. `java helloworld` will not work because the class is called HelloWorld?)

Comment: @k314159 I've double checked this one multiple times. Looks good to me.

Comment: `src=HelloWorld.java;ls $src && cat $src && javac $src && java -classpath . $src` Please paste that into your terminal, execute it and post the output

Comment: HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 System.out.println("Hello World!");
 
    }
    
}
error: file not found: HelloWorld.java

Comment: @g00se: I guess it should have been:
src=HelloWorld.java;ls $src && cat $src && javac $src && java HelloWorld

Comment: Which results in:
HelloWorld.java
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 System.out.println("Hello World!");
 
    }
    
}
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld

Comment: Actually no. java executable now will execute source files. Try instead `src=HelloWorld.java;ls $src && cat $src && javac -verbose $src && java -classpath . $src`

Comment: Yes, but $src is actually referring to the source file - not the compiled HelloWorld.class file

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right. So the last command just `java -classpath . HelloWorld`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243791/discussion-between-aknott-and-g00se).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @g00se in the comments, I've figured it out:

My source code `HelloWorld.java` and the compiled code `HelloWorld.class` was located in a subdirectory of `/Users/<myLocalUserName>/Documents/`. Moving the code above the level of the `Documents` directory works.

So, I've created an appropriate directory ABOVE this level (=*source diretory*) and a symbolic link (=*target*) in my existing file structure UNDER my `Documents` directory with

```sh
ln -s <pathToSource> <pathToTarget>
```

My best guess right now is, that this relates to the combination of *MacOS* versions and *java* versions, as stated above in the question.

Hope that can be helpful for anybody else, feeling like a **NOOP**.